# How do I combine these two queries into one?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Query1:**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT FirstOfFrequencyMHz, Min(LicenceData.distance) AS CoFX
FROM [Freq List], LicenceData
WHERE ((([LicenceData].class_stat) Like 'F*') And (([LicenceData].type_lc)="A") And (([LicenceData].frequency) Between FirstOfFrequencyMHz-0.0249 And FirstOfFrequencyMHz+0.0249))
GROUP BY FirstOfFrequencyMHz
```

**Query2:**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT FirstOfFrequencyMHz, Min(LicenceData.distance) AS CoMO
FROM [Freq List], LicenceData
WHERE ((([LicenceData].class_stat) Like 'M*') And (([LicenceData].type_lc)="A") And (([LicenceData].frequency) Between FirstOfFrequencyMHz-0.0249 And FirstOfFrequencyMHz+0.0249))
GROUP BY FirstOfFrequencyMHz
```

**Combined Query Attempt:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstOfFrequencyMHz, 

(SELECT Min(distance) AS Expr1
FROM [Freq List], LicenceData
WHERE ((([LicenceData].class_stat) Like 'F*') And (([LicenceData].type_lc)="A") And (([LicenceData].frequency) Between FirstOfFrequencyMHz-0.0249 And FirstOfFrequencyMHz+0.0249))) as COFX,

(SELECT Min(distance) AS Expr1
FROM [Freq List], LicenceData
WHERE ((([LicenceData].class_stat) Like 'M*') And (([LicenceData].type_lc)="A") And (([LicenceData].frequency) Between FirstOfFrequencyMHz-0.0249 And FirstOfFrequencyMHz+0.0249))) as COMO

FROM [Freq List]
```

My posted combined query attempt does not return the correct values, all cells for the CoFX and CoMO columns have the same number in them.

The two queries work independently I just need to know how to combine them (there are 4 total queries I need to combine that are similar to the first 2 posted queries) or it it is even possible to combine them.

Comment: I can't see how your sample input relates to your sample output.

Comment: I've read it a few times and my head hurts, how are you bringing in the CoChnl / AdjChnl, can you simplify your explanation at all please?

Comment: Added info/simplification (I hope). Also the input i put in was only a small sample of the rows in that table. the output is essential the center frequency and the closest distance with an active licence for both fixed and mobile licence classes for each center frequency.

Comment: You must define what you mean by combining. The only difference between the 2 queries I can see is that Like "F*" and Like "M*". If you combine them in the WHERE clause your result will contain multiple rows, but your example seems to indicate that you want a separate column for each result. Please clarify.

Comment: I thought it was fairly obvious what I was trying to accomplish from the query combination attempt I had posted. You also seem to have realized it yourself. I am wanting to get one query that has the FirstOfFrequencyMHz, CoFX, and CoMO columns as they appear individually in the two individual queries.

Comment: In both Query 1 & 2 I can't see how you are linking the License and Freq List tables?

Comment: There is no link or join since there are no exact matches. The Freq List table has a small list of Center Frequencies that are used to create a range of frequencies to be used as a search/filter criteria in the where statement to get the Minimum distance of a subset of information. It was my understanding that by having 2 or more tables separated by a comma allows you to use/query both tables without having a specific join statement.

Comment: @Bryan I'm not sure it can be done in that way but perhaps with sub-selects, please see my proposed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the best way, as there is no direct link between the tables, you need to use sub-selects in order to ensure they are referenced correctly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FirstOfFrequencyMHz,
(
SELECT Min(L.Distance)
FROM LicenceData As L
WHERE L.Class_Stat Like 'F*'
AND L.Type_LC = 'A'
AND L.Frequency Between F.FirstOfFrequencyMHz-0.0249 And F.FirstOfFrequency+0.0249
) CoFX,
(
SELECT Min(L2.Distance)
FROM LicenceData As L2
WHERE L2.Class_Stat Like 'M*'
AND L2.Type_LC = 'A'
AND L2.Frequency Between F.FirstOfFrequencyMHz-0.0249 And F.FirstOfFrequency+0.0249
) CoMO
FROM [Freq List] As F
```

Best of luck : )

Comment: Your welcome, took me a while to get my head round this one : )

Comment: I've gotten a few feedbacks to that affect. I am still surprised that so many people seemed to find my question confusing (after I redid the question, how I was asking it to begin with was admittedly potentially confusing if not inevitably confusing). Did you have troubles understanding what I was trying to achieve or how to achieve it? The main reason I ask is that I have known communication  issues due to the way I tend to phrase things and I'm always trying to get better.

Comment: @Bryan It was ok after been re-written, your proposed SQL statement really helped as I could get the idea from reading it, sometimes it's easier to understand than a paragraph about what your trying to achieve. The shorter and simpler the better to be honest.